# OnTouchListener coordinates being incorrect

Tags: java, android, image, touch, coordinates

I have an OnTouchListener however when I actually test my program and touch the screen is displays a colour that is not what it should be. I tested using blocks of colours and it works however the coordinates are still off and if you touch too far on one colour it will show you a different one. I believe this is because the the coordinates produced are in comparison to the whole screen instead of the image view - where i want it to be selected from. How would i make the OnTouchListener be for just the image view and not the whole screen? Thank you.

```
final Bitmap bitmap2 = ((BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
    imageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {


            Matrix inverse = new Matrix();
            v.getMatrix().invert(inverse);
            float[] touchPoint = new float[] {event.getX(), event.getY()};
            inverse.mapPoints(touchPoint);
            int x = Integer.valueOf((int)touchPoint[0]);
            int y = Integer.valueOf((int)touchPoint[1]);


          //  int x = (int) event.getX();
           // int y = (int) event.getY();
            int pixel = bitmap2.getPixel(x, y);


            int red = Color.red(pixel);
            int blue = Color.blue(pixel);
            int green = Color.green(pixel);

            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(output.getAbsolutePath());
            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setAntiAlias(true);
            paint.setColor(Color.rgb(red,green,blue));


            Bitmap workingBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap);
            Bitmap mutableBitmap = workingBitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);


            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mutableBitmap);
            canvas.drawRect(50, 50, 500, 250, paint);

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.Image_view);
            imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(mutableBitmap);


            return true;
            }

    });

}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I believe this is because the the coordinates produced are in
>   comparison to the whole screen

Yes, you need to do some simple deduction to get the touch coordinates on the imageView:

```
int[] imgCoords = new int[2];
imageView.getLocationOnScreen(imgCoords);
```

get the X,Y of the touch and take away the imageView coordinates from it:

```
int wholeX = (int) event.getX();
int wholeY = (int) event.getY();

int imageX = wholeX - imgCoords[0];
int imageY = wholeY - imgCoords[1];
```

Comment: The colour is still not what it should be and i dont know why @Rayes

Comment: would it be something to do with the imageView size?                <ImageView
        android:layout_width="1000dp"
        android:layout_height="1000dp"
        android:id="@+id/Image_view"
        android:contentDescription="@string/image_cd_camera"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"/>   @Rayes